# Privoxy - C# can't open forwarded file

Tags: c#

I write app with using [Privoxy](http://privoxy.org)

```
forward /spacemap/xml/maps.php 127.0.0.1:9002
```

Next in C#

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9002);
tcpListener.Start();
while (true)
{
TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
HTTP HTTP = new HTTP(tcpClient);
HTTP.Read();
}
```

In method `HTTP.Read()` I read all headers from request to this file(/spacemap/xml/maps.php) and it works fine.

But when I get requestURL(good) and I'm trying open that url nothing happens.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string download = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.com/spacemap/xml/maps.php");
Console.WriteLine(download);
```

But download variable is empty. (link in webbrowser works fine).

I'm trying HttpWebRequest, WebRequest, WebClient - and nothing, other links works fine.

Any ideas?